# Radon-Nikodym derivative of sum of two measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

**Problem Statement:** Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two finite measures such that $\nu \ll \mu$, let $\rho = \mu + \nu$, and note that since $\mu(A) \le \rho(A)$, and $\nu(A) \le \rho(A)$, we have $\mu \ll \rho$ and $\nu \ll \rho$. Prove that if $f = d\mu/d\rho$ and $g = d\nu/d\rho$, then $f +g = 1$ and $d\nu = (g/f) \, d\mu$.

**My attempt at a solution:** For the first part, I said
$$\mu(A) = \int_A f \, d\rho \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \nu(A) = \int_A g \, d\rho,$$
therefore, $\mu(A) + \nu(A) = \int_A (f+g) \, d\rho$. Now, $\mu(A) + \nu(A) = (\mu+\nu)(A)$, and $\mu + \nu$ is another finite measure, so we have that $f+g$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu + \nu$ w.r.t $\rho$, written as $f + g = \frac{d(\mu+\nu)}{d\rho}$. Now, we consider $\int_A 1 \, d\rho = \int \chi_A \, d\rho = \rho(A) = \mu(A) + \nu(A) = (\mu+\nu)(A)$, and by the uniqueness of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, $f + g = 1$ a.e. However, I am not sure how to prove that $f+ g = 1$ everywhere - am I going about this proof completely wrong, or is there something else I need to do from here to show this?

For this next part, I am not entirely sure what the question is asking. We know that there is some non-negative, integrable w.r.t. $\mu$ function $h$ such that $\nu(A) = \int_A h \, d\mu$. Are we being asked to prove that $h = g/f$? If so, it would be easy to write something like $\int_A (g/f) \, d\mu = \int_A\frac{d\nu \, d\rho}{d\rho \, d\mu} \, d\mu = \int_A \, d\nu = \nu(A)$, thus showing that $g/f = h$ a.e.; however, I don't know that we can manipulate Radon-Nikodym derivatives in the way, yet, so there must be something else going on here, and I don't know how to go about proving it!

Comment: My answer was somewhat mangled.  Now I've changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your argument is OK. You can only prove that $f+g=1$ a.e.$[\rho]$, because if you change $f$ in a set of $\rho$-measure 0, then the new function, let us call it $\tilde f$, will also satisfy $\tilde f = d\mu/d\rho$  and  $\mu(A) = \int_A \tilde f \, d\rho$.
2. Note that $\nu \ll \mu \ll \rho$.  It is easy to show that 
   $$\frac{d\nu}{d\rho} =  \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\frac{d\mu}{d\rho}$$

Let $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=h$. We have then $\nu(A) = \int_A h \, d\mu=\int_A hf \, d\rho$, then by the uniqueness of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, $g=hf$ a.e.

Now (and this is an important part) because $\rho=\mu+\nu$ and $\nu \ll \mu$, we also have that $\rho \ll \mu$ which allows us to conclude that $f=\frac{d\mu}{d\rho}>0$ a.e.. So from  $g=hf$ a.e. we get $h=g/f$ a.e., that is $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=g/f$.

Comment: Is there a simple way to show what you wrote than proving it through the simple functions method?

Comment: @gesa  We don't need simple functions here. I have included more details on how to show $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=g/f$. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove $f+g=1$ everywhere, because counterexamples can readily be found.  Where the exercise says $f+g=1$ there must be a convention in force that says that is to be construed as almost everywhere.

Since $\mu \ll \rho$, there is a Radon--Nikodym derivative $f=d\mu/d\rho$.
$$
\mu(A) = \int_A f\,d\rho = \int_A f \,\Big( \frac 1 g\, d\nu \Big) \tag 1
$$
The second equality in $(1)$ above should work if $\rho \ll \nu$. See if you can prove that by using the hypothesis that $\nu\ll\mu$ and the definition of $\rho$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - the book that I am using has a similar problem that mentions the a.e. condition, so I was unsure if I was just missing something on this one.

Comment: I am a little uncomfortable saying that $\frac{1}{g}\ d\nu = d\rho$, because even though that makes sense to me, up until this point, I only know that we call the R-N derivative $g d\rho = d\nu$, but we don't necessarily know yet that we can divide the $d \nu$ and $d \rho$ around as you have done... is there a simple way to prove that that is ok?

Comment: Sorry, I think something is strange in your answer.  As far as I know, if $\nu\ll\mu$ then there is a Randon-Nikodym derivative $d\nu /d\mu$ and we can write $d\nu=\frac{d\nu }{d\mu} d\mu$.

Comment: OK, I had that backwards.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have that

$$\rho(A) = \int_{A} 1 d\rho$$

And

$$\rho(A) = \mu(A)+\nu(A) =  \int_{A} f d\rho+ \int_{A} g d\rho= \int_{A} f+g d\rho$$

And as this is true for all $A$ measurable, it's a classical result that this imply that $f+g=1$ a.e (for $\rho$)

For the second one, just remark that

$$\int_A 1 d\nu = \int_A g d\rho = \int_A \frac{g}{f} f d\rho = \int_A  \frac{g}{f} d\mu$$